# ISD 1820 using Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno

I have to play audio files using an isd1820 sound module. I am using arduino uno microcontroller but I am able to play only one file. Is there a way I can play different audio files according to need?

Comment: how are you playing one file?

Comment: Please provide a link to the exact sound module, that you have.